# insert date from resultset to arraylist

Tags: java, arraylist

```
ResultSet rs=ps.executeQuery();  
List<<DATE>> days = new ArrayList<DATE>();  
while(rs.next()) {  
   unavailable_days.add(rs.getDate(1));  
}
```

I have a Prepared Statement query, which I am storing in the ResultSet. The result set consists of two columns, 1st Index-Date,2nd Index-an Id.

I want to get the dates from the result set and store it in an array or arraylist.
But trying this coode I get an error under .add which says "The method add(DATE) in the type List is not applicable for the arguments (Date)"

Please help..

Comment: java.sql.Date is not equal to your DATE object.  So, you need to change that DATE to java.sql.Date object List.

Comment: Could you please show the code for your class `DATE`? Adding to Eran's answer: You must _convert_ a `java.sql.Date` to a `DATE`. Knowing the code for it enables us to help you with the conversion.

Comment: Additionally, you've got double angle brackets in `List<<DATE>>` for some reason...

Comment: @JonSkeet sorry that was a writing error. Using the Java.sql.Date class works, Thank you everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rs.getDate()` returns an instance of `java.sql.Date`. Your List expects `DATE` objects (note that Java is case sensitive).

You need :

```
import java.sql.Date; // or import.java.util.Date;
...
List<Date> days = new ArrayList<>();
```

Note that `rs.getDate()` returns a `java.sql.Date`, which is a sub-class of `java.util.Date`.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming date is your defined Class which have java.sql.Date date field;

```
List<DATE> days = new ArrayList<DATE>(); 

while(rs.next()) {  
    DATE d=new DATE();
    d.setDate(rs.getDate(1)); 
    days.add(d); 
}
```